# 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Component'

Tags: typescript

**Updated with an MRE**

I have an Entity Component System in my game library and I am trying to pass a class into a `getComponent()` method that is extended from my base Game Object class.

I want the `getComponent()` method to accept any class that extends the Component class but still keep its Type when it is returned.

Any help rewriting this in a proper way that settles the issues raised by TS I be happy

Error

```
Type 'Component' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'Component' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Component'
```

Component.ts

```
export abstract class Component
{
    constructor()
    {}
}
```

gameObject.ts

```
import { Component } from "./component";

export class GameObject
{
    name: string;

    components: Component[] = [];

    /** Returns the component of type if the GameObject has one attached, null if it doesn't. */
    getComponent<T extends Component>(componentTypeToReturn: { new(...args: any[]): T; }): T | null
    {
        for (let index = 0; index < this.components.length; index++)
        {
            if (this.components[index] instanceof componentTypeToReturn) return this.components[index]; // this return statement is where the error is
        }

        console.error(`Could not get component of type ${componentTypeToReturn} on GameObject ${this.name}`);

        return null;
    }
}
```

component that extends Component abstract base class

sprite.ts

```
import { Component } from "./component";

export default class Sprite extends Component
{

}
```

usage example

main.ts

```
import { GameObject } from "./gameObject";
import Sprite from "./sprite";


const player = new GameObject();

const spriteOnPlayer = player.getComponent(Sprite);
```

Comment: typo in the example, thank you. the problem is still the same.

Comment: The issue you're seeing is [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530), you can't guard a property access of the form `x[k]` if `k` is a wide type like `number` or `string`.  The "standard" approach to that is to copy the property to a new variable and guard the variable instead, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5kq0W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that solves my issue, thank you kindly - I will read up on the docs supplied to get a good grasp on what the issue is. I will mark your answer as solved when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  TypeScript doesn't currently support [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type of a property unless the property key is a known [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  So you can use dotted syntax like `if (x.y)`, or bracket syntax like `if (x["y"])`, but if you use `if (x[k])` if the type of `k` is something wider than a literal, like `string`, then it does not act as a type guard.

In your case, `this.components[index]` can't be narrowed, because `index` is of type `number`, which is too wide. You could narrow `this.components[0]`, but that's not what you want to do.

---

For now, the "standard" approach to dealing with this limitation is to copy the property into a new variable and then perform your checks on that, since variables don't have the problem. In your case that looks like:

```
getComponent<T extends Component>(
  componentTypeToReturn: { new(...args: any[]): T; }
): T | null {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.components.length; index++) {
        const c = this.components[index] // copy to another variable first
        if (c instanceof componentTypeToReturn) 
            return c; // okay
    }
    console.error(`no ${componentTypeToReturn} on ${this.name}`);
    return null;
}
```

which compiles without error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyMQG8BYAKAXqWMigFd5soAKASgQoQC+tITVq0UaDAHFguEgHkQAKxLw+tBgiKySALgTMAlkQDmCALwIARMGQB3YAE8wASSKGIABSjZ8YKwDcYnQMsHiEpORg+jgExGQQANoAuhYIKUGiIfQmJBCxEQkAPAAqCCQAHhBkACYYBfHkAHycYXGRECWO+CQl2ABKeSxQRPr8pHacAHQzwFAm0QjARI4p3PolAYLrCGUAPlosyMjq2ZoIAGYcCJzIeQjGNZVpAAxbj89FCBAAFoZgUzahSiUzupl+7yITwqAGoYbxqGdzqEmIhYGlfv9AeFGhAwIkPhVUgB6YmMfCOb7YJZEbC-EhQBAANzmhlAd0uhigkA0yPOhguN3Rxkgy1gJGwgqBuK6PT6gwgwyIvF5fL5UCGIyQW1JCGwAGsnKrziI1WEiGBsHcpgyfFwAAY4I41LR0hC5NE4jp6wUQbokBAAEgo0o6st6A01RAEeqICBkckUKjUwcxAO0cgE9u4mTVGsVWqIR2QuYYIhEwXEqHQCAAyvgoB4A5VqlD6l6EqdhJWsubIAh8KhHAy0hN4zok6oIDxMuJUQYG035ERPEOR5ZB04GVMPQ0Opx643qjnaEA)

Answer (score 1):

With `as` keyword you can tell TypeScript that the return is a `T` type. Like this:

```
if (this.components[index] instanceof componentTypeToReturn) {
            return this.components[index] as T;
   }
```

Comment: The `instanceof Component` part was a typo that has been fixed, so this answer should probably be edited also.

Comment: Nice, I made an edit.